# What is a way to increase the performance for rendering large Grids in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, performance

I am building a react + typescript + vite [Nonogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonogram) App.

You can see the lacking performance for larger grid sizes in the gh pages live demo:
https://timonkobusch.github.io/nonogram/
Here is the full code for it:
https://github.com/timonkobusch/nonogram

My Question and ideas are:

1. Is there even a way, to handle large sizes of elements realistically in React with high performance without having to use an animation library here? (This is not what I want to be honest)
2. Will optimizations even help, or just very small improvements that are marginal and not noticable?
3. Should I consider extracting more attributes from the nonogram class to increase performance and reduce rerenders here? How would I do it effectively.
4. Could global state management be a good solution? Like redux (not sure)?
5. Maybe swap to grid and handle more styling inside css if possible?

Here are the 2 most important files that take up (obviously) the longest time to render:
NonogramGrid.tsx:

```
const NonogramGrid = ({
    nonogram,
    onMouseDownHandler,
    onMouseOverHandler,
    gameRunning,
}: INonogramGridProps) => {
    const [selectedCell, setSelectedCell] = useState<{
        row: number;
        column: number;
    }>({ row: -1, column: -1 });

    const handleMouseDown =
        (row: number, col: number) => (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (!gameRunning || nonogram.progress.isWon) return;
            onMouseDownHandler(row, col);
        };

    const handleMouseOver =
        (row: number, col: number) => (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (!gameRunning || nonogram.progress.isWon) return;
            setSelectedCell({ row, column: col });
            onMouseOverHandler(row, col);
        };

    const handleMouseLeave = () => {
        setSelectedCell({ row: -1, column: -1 });
    };

    const validSizes = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25];
    const sizeClass = validSizes.includes(nonogram.size)
        ? `grid-${nonogram.size}x${nonogram.size}`
        : "grid-15x15";

    return (
        <div className={`content ${sizeClass}`}>
            <Hints
                hintLines={nonogram.hints.rows}
                finishedLines={nonogram.finishedLines.rows}
                gameRunning={gameRunning && !nonogram.progress.isWon}
                classIdentifier={"left-hints"}
            />
            <table>
                <Hints
                    hintLines={nonogram.hints.columns}
                    finishedLines={nonogram.finishedLines.columns}
                    gameRunning={gameRunning && !nonogram.progress.isWon}
                    classIdentifier={"top-hints"}
                />
                <tbody className="table">
                    {Array.from({ length: nonogram.size }).map((_, row) => {
                        return (
                            <tr key={row} className="row">
                                {Array.from({ length: nonogram.size }).map(
                                    (_, col) => {
                                        const fifthRowBorder =
                                            row === 4 ? "fifth-row" : "";
                                        const highlighted =
                                            selectedCell.row === row ||
                                            selectedCell.column === col
                                                ? "highlighted"
                                                : "";
                                        const hideCell = gameRunning
                                            ? ""
                                            : "hide-cell";
                                        const gameWon = nonogram.progress.isWon
                                            ? "game-won"
                                            : "";
                                        let colored = "empty";
                                        switch (nonogram.grid[row][col]) {
                                            case 1:
                                                colored = "colored";
                                                break;
                                            case 2:
                                                colored = "crossed";
                                                break;
                                            case 3:
                                                colored = "wrongColored";
                                                break;
                                            case 4:
                                                colored = "wrongCrossed";
                                                break;
                                        }
                                        return (
                                            <td
                                                key={col}
                                                className={`cell ${fifthRowBorder}`}
                                                onMouseDown={handleMouseDown(
                                                    row,
                                                    col
                                                )}
                                                onMouseOver={handleMouseOver(
                                                    row,
                                                    col
                                                )}
                                                onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
                                            >
                                                {row > 0 && row % 5 === 0 && (
                                                    <div className="fifth-row-border"></div>
                                                )}
                                                {col > 0 && col % 5 === 0 && (
                                                    <div className="fifth-col-border"></div>
                                                )}
                                                <div
                                                    id="cell"
                                                    className={`${colored} ${highlighted} ${hideCell} ${gameWon}`}
                                                ></div>
                                            </td>
                                        );
                                    }
                                )}
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
};

export default NonogramGrid;
```

And App.tsx which handles the state of game and nonogram:

```
import "components/App.scss";
import NonogramGrid from "./NonogramGrid/NonogramGrid";
import { Nonogram } from "modules/Nonogram";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import GameController from "components/GameController/GameController";
import PlayController from "components/PlayController/PlayController";
import useTimer from "components/utils/useTimer";
import AppHeader from "components/AppHeader/AppHeader";
import About from "components/About/About";
import workerURL from "./utils/createClassWorker?worker&url";

const enum MarkLock {
    UNSET = 0,
    ROW = 1,
    COL = 2,
}

const App = () => {
    const [nonogram, setNonogram] = useState(() => new Nonogram(10));
    const [nonogramHistory, setNonogramHistory] = useState<Nonogram[]>([]);
    const [mouseDown, setMouseDown] = useState(false);
    const [marking, setMarking] = useState(true);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [clearMode, setClearMode] = useState(false);
    const { seconds, resetTimer, startTimer, pauseTimer } = useTimer();
    const [gameRunning, setgameRunning] = useState(false);

    const [clickCoords, setClickCoords] = useState({ row: 0, column: 0 });
    const [markLock, setMarkLock] = useState(MarkLock.UNSET);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleMouseUp = () => {
            if (mouseDown) {
                setMouseDown(false);
            }
        };
        const handleFKeyPress = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
            if (e.key === "f") {
                setMarking(!marking);
            }
        };
        document.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
        document.addEventListener("keypress", handleFKeyPress);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
            document.removeEventListener("keypress", handleFKeyPress);
        };
    });

    const handleUndo = () => {
        ...
    };

    const handleMouseDown = (x: number, y: number) => {
        ...
    };

    const handleMouseOver = (x: number, y: number) => {
        ...
    };
    const handleGenerate = (size: number) => {
        ...
    };

    const handleReset = () => {
        ...
    };

    const handlePause = () => {
        ...
    };
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <AppHeader />
            <div className="App-content">
                <div className="ControlField">
                    <GameController
                        handleGenerate={handleGenerate}
                        handleReset={handleReset}
                        gameWon={nonogram.progress.isWon}
                        loading={loading}
                    />
                    <PlayController
                        progress={nonogram.progress}
                        seconds={seconds}
                        handlePause={handlePause}
                        gameRunning={gameRunning}
                        handleUndo={handleUndo}
                        undoActive={nonogramHistory.length > 0}
                        marking={marking}
                        toggleMarking={() => setMarking(!marking)}
                    />
                    <About />
                </div>
                <NonogramGrid
                    nonogram={nonogram}
                    onMouseDownHandler={handleMouseDown}
                    onMouseOverHandler={handleMouseOver}
                    gameRunning={gameRunning}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

I searched for the problem and mostly find solutions with react-window, which is not the solution here because the grid is always fully visible.

If you have experience with it could you give me a direction how you solved it?
Is using an animation library the solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see there is a problem with the timer - the timer is implemented inside hook useTimer, which is imported in App component. Whenever a custom hook rerender, the component in which the hook is imported rerender too. That means on every second there is new rerendering. I wrote code, which memorize component Nonogramgrid, because there are a lot of expensive iterations. Here are the changes:

```
const memoizedNonogramGrid = useMemo(() => {
    console.log("rerender the grid")
    return (
        <NonogramGrid
            nonogram={nonogram}
            onMouseDownHandler={handleMouseDown}
            onMouseOverHandler={handleMouseOver}
            gameRunning={gameRunning}
        />
    )
}, [gameRunning, handleMouseDown, handleMouseOver, nonogram])

const handleMouseDown = useMemo(() => {
    return (x: number, y: number) => {
        setNonogramHistory([...nonogramHistory, new Nonogram(nonogram)]);

        const updatedGrid = new Nonogram(nonogram);
        updatedGrid.click(x, y, marking);
        setNonogram(updatedGrid);

        // Set mouse state
        setMouseDown(true);
        setClickCoords({ row: y, column: x });
        setMarkLock(MarkLock.UNSET);
        if (nonogram.grid[x][y] === 0) {
            setClearMode(false);
        } else {
            setClearMode(true);
        }
        if (updatedGrid.progress.isWon) {
            pauseTimer();
        }
    };
}, [nonogram, marking, nonogramHistory, pauseTimer])

const handleMouseOver = useMemo(() => {
    return (x: number, y: number) => {
        if (mouseDown) {
            if (x === clickCoords.column && y === clickCoords.row) {
                return;
            }
            if (markLock === MarkLock.UNSET) {
                if (x === clickCoords.column) {
                    setMarkLock(MarkLock.COL);
                } else if (y === clickCoords.row) {
                    setMarkLock(MarkLock.ROW);
                }
            }
            if (markLock === MarkLock.COL) {
                x = clickCoords.column;
            } else if (markLock === MarkLock.ROW) {
                y = clickCoords.row;
            }

            const updatedGrid = new Nonogram(nonogram as Nonogram);
            updatedGrid.setCell(x, y, marking, clearMode);
            setNonogram(updatedGrid);
            if (updatedGrid.progress.isWon) {
                pauseTimer();
            }
        }
    };
}, [clearMode, clickCoords.column, clickCoords.row, markLock, nonogram, mouseDown, marking, pauseTimer])

const pauseTimer = useMemo(() => {
    return () => {
        setActive(false);
    };
}, [])
```

Of course, the memorization can be done with useCallback hook.

The second change which I've made is to pass initial value to the nonogram state, since it is a good practice not to pass function, just a value, because on every rerender there is a execution of that function. In other words the CPU creates new Nonogram(10). Here is the code:

```
const initialNonogramState = new Nonogram(10)

const App = () => {
    const [nonogram, setNonogram] = useState(initialNonogramState);
```

Next, there is still a problem with Nonogram grid component - on every mouse over, there are rerenders of the component and every rerender produce new iterations. I am looking right now on some logic to create the components and just change the props. I am inspired from react-data-table-component library, since they have nice memoization of tables.

Comment: Thank you really much for your input. Really cool that you also made a pull request on github. Thank you for your time you made my day!